# Text doesn't show when a modal window has a lot of text

Tags: html, css

I'm making a modal window centered horizontally and vertically.

The problem is when the window has a lot of text. Some text (top) doesn't show.

Thanks.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel">
  <div>
    1</br>
    2</br>
    3...
  </div>
</div>

A lot of text. </br>
A lot of text. </br>
A lot of text...
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#panel {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Running code: https://jsfiddle.net/dwsr6c71/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: fixed;` is the problem or add `max-height = 100%`

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dwsr6c71/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `max-height = 100%` to modal, it will make this modal's height not larger, than parent. Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dwsr6c71/1/

And the snippet:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#panel {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

#modal {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="modal">
    1</br>
    2</br>
    3</br>
    4</br>
    5</br>
    6</br>
    7</br>
    8</br>
    9</br>
    10</br>
    11</br>
    12</br>
    13</br>
    14</br>
    15</br>
    16</br>
    17</br>
    18</br>
    19</br>
    20</br>
    21</br>
    22</br>
    23</br>
    24</br>
    25</br>
    26</br>
    27</br>
    28</br>
    29</br>
    30</br>
  </div>
</div>

Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
Some text. </br>
```